# Image URL to Base64

Tags: web-services, api, image-processing, base64

Are there any public Web Service APIs that allow submission of an Image URL and return a Base64 encoded version of that image? Here's an example: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data

Two reasons I want this:

1. I don't know much server-side, so it would be nice to avoid coding it myself.
2. Using the HTML5 Canvas + external URLs + .toDataURL = Security Exception (cross domain issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any security considerations, you can do this VERY trivially in php:

```
<?php

echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));
```

Don't be scared of "server-side".

Comment: I should be honest and say I don't know anything server-side. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter